# Can I use regex to find typos or alternate spellings of a person's name when searching a rest API databse?

Tags: python, html, json, regex

Using the senate.gov website's Lobbying Disclosure Act (LDA) API, I was able to create a database of each individual donation given by lobbyists or organizations that lobby to specific candidates for congressional office.

However, the government's LDA data is rather unorganized as the lobbyists who fill out the forms will often spell the politicians names' incorrectly or use alternate spellings.

Ex: Lobbyists could be donating to the same candidate but could write the payee as John Smith, Jonathan Smith, Jon Smith, etc.

So I am attempting to use regular expressions to ensure my Python program doesn't miss any typos or alternate spellings...

Here is what I had before that worked but didn't account for alternate spellings (I don't want to manually input John Smith, Jonathan Smith, Jon Smith each time, I'd rather just use regex to do: J.*n Smith)

```
import requests
import json
import csv

Candidate = John Smith

Payee_Parameter = {
    "contribution_payee": Candidate,
    "dt_posted": "ascending",
    "key": "1234"
}


ContributionsLink = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/contributions/"
response = requests.get(ContributionsLink, params=Payee_Parameter)

data = json.loads(response.text)
lines = json.dumps(response.json(),indent=4)

#The rest of my code after this just organizes the results by category into csv file
```

Now here is my thought process to account for alt spellings and typos with regex. It probably did not work because I don't think you can pass regex into url query parameters.

```
import requests
import json
import csv
import re

Candidate = r'J.*n Smith'

pattern = re.compile(Candidate)

Payee_Parameter = {
    "contribution_payee": pattern,
    "dt_posted": "ascending",
    "key": "1234"
}

ContributionsLink = "https://lda.senate.gov/api/v1/contributions/"
response = requests.get(ContributionsLink, params=Payee_Parameter)
data = json.loads(response.text)
lines = json.dumps(response.json(),indent=4)



# matches = pattern.finditer(data) <-- Maybe this can come in handy? I am new to regex and decent with Python.
```

Any ideas on how I can account for those alternate spellings/typos with the LDA API? Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you are correct that you can't pass regex in as a query parameter. You most likely will need to collect all of the data locally, then sort the data on your local machine. I haven't checked, but is there a way to get a list of all payee's? If so, get that list, find the duplicates/misspelling, and then loop through that list, fetching the data for each.

Comment: Hi Waylan! Thanks for offering your help! Problem is that there are 490,000 filings going back to 2008 and each of those filings contains sometimes hundreds or thousands of individual contribution items. Would my local machine even be able to handle that type of data storage and how would I store it? I have never done anything like this before haha so have no clue. I do like what @Nuno said below about using fuzzy matching.

Comment: I guess the best option is:
Save the entire database somewhere on my computer than iterate through each of the honorees/payees to get the candidates I want and could use either regex or fuzzy matching to do so. This way, I can ensure that I don't miss any of the typos or alt spellings!

Just wonder how long this will take and what format I need to save it in. Any suggestions on this? Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Yes, I don't see other way to do that. Save it locally as @Wailan suggests. You can store these json documents in a ElasticSearch database and then query them pretty fast using fuzzymatching.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

Or you can store them in textfiles in your local file system but "querying" will be more slow. The solution depends:
If you to search "John Smith" once in a lifetime, save files locally in the file system. If you want to do this seriously, I think its better to store it in ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach would be fuzzy matching. It vectorizes the character string and then compares it's distance using an algorithm. Ideal if you misspell random characters.

Take a look at this:
https://towardsdatascience.com/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python-68f240d910fe

It would work like this:

Install fuzzywuzzy

```
pip install fuzzywuzzy
```

Run this:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process


print(fuzz.ratio("John Doe","Joe Dow"))
print(fuzz.ratio("John Doe","John M. Doe"))
print(fuzz.ratio("John Doe","Billy Jean"))
```

Output:

```
67
84
22
```

Comment: Hi Nuno! Thanks for making me aware of this great tool! If I were to save the entire database like @Waylan said, do you think that it would be better to use fuzzy matching or regex to find the honorees/payees that I want?